# retrieve data from a thread in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a thread in python which handled receive OSC packets...
I need to retrieve datas from osc in my main function. How could get data from thread out of the thread ?
Here's the code to demonstrate my issue:

## TRY WIH CLASS, BUT STILL "DATA IS NOT DEFINED

```
import OSC
import threading
import atexit
#------OSC Server-------------------------------------#
receive_address = '127.0.0.1', 7402

# OSC Server. there are three different types of server. 
s = OSC.ThreadingOSCServer(receive_address)

# this registers a 'default' handler (for unmatched messages)
s.addDefaultHandlers()

class receive:
    def printing_handler(addr, tags, data, source):
        
        if addr=='/data':
            self.data=data.pop(0)
            s.addMsgHandler("/data", printing_handler)
            return data
        


    def main(self):
        # Start OSCServer
        #Main function...I need to retrieve 'data' from the OSC THREAD here
        print "Starting OSCServer"
        st = threading.Thread(target=s.serve_forever)
        st.start()
       

reception=receive()
reception.main()
plouf = data.reception()
print plouf
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want to use content of parameter data from function printing_handler in function main?

Comment: Change `plouf = data.reception()` to `plouf = reception.data`

Comment: thanks Thomas ! 
Now It gives me this error: receive instance has no attribute 'data'
I'm keeping searching

Comment: Your code is very screwed up. Change `def printing_handler(addr, tags, data, source)` to `def printing_handler(self, addr, tags, data, source)`, or make it a `static method`. Also, rename the `main` function to `__init__`, and remove the `reception.main()` call. You never actually call the `printing_handler()` function, so there's no data to retrieve. That's why you're getting an error.

Comment: thanks...my issue is that printing_handler() is never evoked because it owns in a thread...Thanks anyway !!

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) from the standard library, or use Global variables.

Comment: Friends don't let friends use Global variables in python :-)

Comment: Although they're bad practice, in very small multithreaded scripts (such as the OP's), they work nicely.

Comment: ok but..class with self.handled seem more complex and I'm still stuck

:-(